# Node package installed, NPM not working

Tags: node.js

I've just started working with an agency that uses Grunt for their code compilation. I've not used Grunt, Node or NPM before. I've installed Node.JS using the Package installer on their website (`node-v0.12.1.pkg`), which is supposed to install NPM at the same time. However, running:

`npm -v`

returns

`-bash: npm: command not found`

Node is installed correctly, but I'm pretty sure my PATHs (whatever they are) are broken, so it doesn't know where to look for NPM. There is a `.npm` folder inside my user directory.

Earlier in the year I did a lot of fiddling about with trying to set up Ruby and Git correctly, installed RVM, and at some point during that process I think I've broken my PATHs. I don't know how they work - is anyone able to help me sort it out so NPM works correctly and I can start using Grunt?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install npm package, you can follow the official doc:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: How would you run `npm install` when `npm` is not found?

Comment: `sudo: npm: command not found`. NPM is meant to be installed with Node. The problem I've got is that NPM can't be found.

Comment: You must install npm in the same folder npm package is located.. id u can't find it , you can see the next video and follow instructions https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally  to install the package npm